# dictionaries, python functions, global and local variables, memory

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, global, local

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
>>> dataDict1 = {'feature1': [], 'feature2': [], 'feature3': []}
>>> features = {0 : 'feature1', 1: 'feature2', 2: 'feature3'}
>>>
>>> def f(data_Dict, featureLabel):
...     data_Dict[featureLabel] = [1, 2]
...     return data_Dict
>>>
>>> for i in range(3):
...     dataDict2 = f(dataDict1, features[i])
...     print dataDict2
...
{'feature2': [], 'feature3': [], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
{'feature2': [1, 2], 'feature3': [], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
{'feature2': [1, 2], 'feature3': [1, 2], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
>>>
>>> dataDict2
{'feature2': [1, 2], 'feature3': [1, 2], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
>>> dataDict3 = f(dataDict2, 'feature4')
>>>
>>> dataDict3
{'feature4': [1, 2], 'feature2': [1, 2], 'feature3': [1, 2], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
>>> dataDict2
>>>
{'feature4': [1, 2], 'feature2': [1, 2], 'feature3': [1, 2], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
```

I think I understand what's going on up to here. But then when I type dataDict1, what I get is exactly the same as dataDict2 and dataDict 3.

```
>>> dataDict1
{'feature4': [1, 2], 'feature2': [1, 2], 'feature3': [1, 2], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
>>>
```

I expected dataDict1 to be

```
{'feature2': [1, 2], 'feature3': [1, 2], 'feature1': [1, 2]}
```

I think I'm not understanding something with the way python return statements work. Or maybe local and global variables. Can someone explain this?

Comment: You are working with a single dict references by different variables. No where do you create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
...     data_Dict[featureLabel] = [1, 2]
```

modifies the argument `data_Dict` in place.  If you don't want (as it seems) for the function to modify it's argument, you need to clone the argument first:

```
...     data_Dict = dict(data_Dict)
...     data_Dict[featureLabel] = [1, 2]
```